# Display only chosen dates in datepicker

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I have history window with date picker but there’s some days without any record in DataBase, I want to disable this days in the datepicker.
Any ideas please.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [DayRender](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/BetterCalendar.aspx?msg=1471924) event handler for disabling the dates in the datepicker. Refer this [sample site](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-ajax/calendar/disabling-calendar-days.aspx) to know.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the DatePicker.BlackoutDates Property. Dates in this collection will appear as disabled on the drop-down calendar.